# How Are "Build Your Own App" Companies Functioning?

Tags: iphone, service, creation

I am seeing a lot companies popping up that are offering services that let you build apps using your own RSS feeds, photo feeds, etc. Some even say that you can instantly have the app run on your iPhone.

How are they doing this? Even if they somehow created a script that could automate the Apple Provisioning Process, aren't they limited to 100 device IDs, and don't their apps still need to be approved?

Are they not being transparent with their customers, or am I missing something big?

http://swebapps.com/

http://www.kanchoo.com/

http://www.appbreeder.com/

And there are a ton more out there

Comment: Can you post a link to such company/app?

Comment: These are just cookie-cutter apps that you swap the graphics and contents.  They aren't really anything more than websites on the iPhone, so it's quite possible that they're doing exactly what they say they are.

Comment: i do not believe it is all streamlined.  everything but the submission/update process is pretty much tho - working for one myself.  the app updates all of it's content(pages, backgrounds, text, data, etc) on it's own without needing an update.  also, it is not all websites shoved into an app. i work with all native iOS/Android frameworks for such a project

Comment: @binnyb Can you tell how they are updating functionality, working around Apple's no interpreted code should be run in the app "law"?

Comment: @Rod : Apple now allows all kinds of interpreted code as long as it is not downloaded.  But web view JavaScript/HTML5 updates can be dynamically downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that they are controling the client on the appStore. You provide content with the constraint of their client.

Looking at swebapps, it looks like they are actually submitting a native app, on your behalf, to Apple. Remains the mystery on how they can update functionality without resubmitting to Apple.

> All apps built through the SwebApps
>   platform rely upon media and data
>   stored on cloud servers. Hosting on
>   cloud servers allows our apps to be
>   updated in real time, without
>   re-submitting updates to Apple and
>   requiring users to download an update